# Combine the rows that have partial same value

Tags: r, aggregate-functions

my dataset looks like this
Name                       Nickname
1   (Franz) Xaver               Vere/i, Verl, Xare, Xav(i), Xaverl, Xide
3   Adolf                       Do(i)lfal, Do(i)lferl
4   Adolf, Adalbert, Adrian     Ade/i
5   Alexander                   Xand(i)

as you can see 3rd and 4th rows contain same value which is "Adolf". It is a single value for the 3rd cell and for the 4th one is a multiple values cell, I need to combine these two cells to have a data frame shows that all possible nicknames for each name and that which names can have same or similar nickname in one row

so it should be like this
Name                            Nickname
3   Adolf, Adalbert, Adrian         Do(i)lfal, Do(i)lferl, Ade/i

Additional, does anyone know how can I change the value like "Do(i)lfal" to "Dolfal, Dilfal" in the same cell, and change "Ade/i" to "Ade, Adi"

I am only allowed to figure it out with Base R, I am very struggled.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you looking for any word match?  There are also some words inside brackets.  Suppose, there is a 'Franz' without bracket in another row, would those be grouped together

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer to your last question:

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Nickname = c("Ade/i", "Do(i)lfal")
)
```

I'm afraid the solution isn't anything elegant:

```
df$Nickname_new[1] <- paste0(sub("(?=.*/)(.*)/.*", "\\1", df$Nickname[1], perl = T), ",", paste0(unlist(str_split(df$Nickname[1], "\\w/")), collapse = ""))
df$Nickname_new[2] <- paste0(sub("(.*)(\\(.*\\))(.*)", "\\1\\3", df$Nickname[2]),",", sub("(.*)(\\w)\\((\\w)\\)(.*)", "\\1\\3\\4", df$Nickname[2]))
```

Result:

```
df
   Nickname  Nickname_new
1     Ade/i       Ade,Adi
2 Do(i)lfal Dolfal,Dilfal
```

Comment: Added new regex

Comment: Could you please give a hint that how can I define x as the col in my dataset? Because the Ade/i is a value of the col of nickname. Thanks a lot.